Unable to find results in vector search when using redis as a vector database
I'm trying to follow the redis documentation example to calculate the distance between two embeddings arrays but I'm using Typescript. I've managed to create an index and load data, but no matter how I run the query on redis I get 0 results.
Using JSON keys
My current setup looks like this (simplified):
const INDEX_NAME = 'idx:jobs';

const client = createClient({
  socket: {
    host: 'cache',
    port: 6379, // Number.parseInt(REDIS_PORT, 10),
    connectTimeout: 10000,
    // tls: true,
  },
});

const schema: RediSearchSchema = {
  '$.title': { type: SchemaFieldTypes.TEXT },
  '$.document': { type: SchemaFieldTypes.TEXT },
  '$.embeddings': { type: SchemaFieldTypes.VECTOR, DIM: 1536, DISTANCE_METRIC: 'COSINE', ALGORITHM: VectorAlgorithms.FLAT, TYPE: 'FLOAT32' }
}

client.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Redis error', { error });
  client.disconnect();
});

app.listen(port, async () => {
  await client.connect();
  await client.ft.create(INDEX_NAME, schema, { PREFIX: 'jobs:', ON: 'JSON' });
  const id1 = randomUUID();
  await client.json.SET(`jobs:${id1}`, '.', { title: 'dummy1', document: 'test stuff', embeddings: embedding });
  const id2 = randomUUID();
  await client.json.SET(`jobs:${id2}`, '.', { title: 'dummy', document: 'test stuff', embeddings: embedding });
  const id3 = randomUUID();
  await client.json.SET(`jobs:${id3}`, '.', { title: 'dummy', document: 'test stuff', embeddings: embedding });
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`, client.isReady);
});

I am calculating the distance using the example's KNN method:
const embeddingArray = []; // This is an array with floats of length 1536
const embeddings = new Float32Array(embeddingArray);

const result = await client.ft.search(
    INDEX_NAME,
    '(*)=>[KNN 3 @embeddings $query_vector AS vector_score]', {
      DIALECT: 2,
      RETURN: ['vector_score', 'title', 'document'],
      PARAMS: {
        'query_vector': Buffer.from(embeddings.buffer),
      },
    }
);

Using Hash keys
I have also tried following the example in the `redis-stack` UI which uses hash keys, basically changing the `json.set` to:
await client.hSet(`jobs:${id1}`, { title: 'dummy1', document: 'test stuff', embeddings: Buffer.from((new Float32Array(embedding)).buffer) });

Changing the index to ON: 'HASH', and querying the index the exact same way. I still get 0 results.
Any pointers or help would be highly appreciated. I believe I'm doing something wrong when converting the data to binary, but I can't find the issue.

I suspect that your embedding is not being stored in Redis the way the model required. I did this with JavaScript and it was a bit fiddly figuring out the types, sizes, and encodings. What model are you using to create the embedding? Can you provide a link to it?

I'm using Azure ADA embeddings model, which returns a 1536 length array of floats and storing the embeddings as they come. Looks like [-0.037722293, 0.04949165, 0.03627376, ...].

Can you share the output of FT.INFO of your indexes? Especially the num_docs, indexing failures and indexing error fields
